# refreshing an external web page when a button is clicked on a web page from a different website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have developed two different `asp.net mvc web application` which has some data pulled from different databases. I would like a refresh a web page on first application when a button is clicked on second webpage using `html meta tags` or what ever is the best.

I have the following `HTML 5` mark up

```
 <td >
   <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: add" value="Add New      Entry" />
 </td>
```

I want to embed a feature to above button which on clicking the button should invoke an event and refresh http://xyz.atlas.com/

**Is there a way I could achieve this?**

Comment: You could use SignalR to send events to each of your applications and respond to them however you like.

Comment: I have been using signalR within both my applications but not sure how I can exchange events between two different applications

Comment: You should have shared service between both application and second applicaton must listen this service when ivoked then refresh itself.

Answer (score 0):

2 approaches with [SignalR](http://signalr.net/),

1. Connect the click event on the page A to call an action to a controller in the A site, and make a service send a message to another controller in site B with an HttpClient, which will fire a message to all clients and will refresh all B pages
2. Connect the click event on A to call an action on a controller in B site and fire the event there to all connected clients